# JModelica refuses to load libhsl.so

Tags: jmodelica

JModelica is refusing to load the file `libhsl.so` as a shared library, even though I have set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable:

> Exception of type: OPTION_INVALID in file "../../../../Ipopt/src/Algorithm/IpAlgBuilder.cpp" at line 321:
>    Exception message: Selected linear solver MA27 not available.
>   Tried to obtain MA27 from shared library "libhsl.so", but the following error occured:
>   libhsl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have tried recompiling and rerunning JModelica in *many* ways.

I have set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` appropriately.

I have run `ldconfig`.

Nothing seems to help.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of revision 7885 of the JModelica trunk, JModelica egregiously violates the [Principle of Least Astonishment](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment).

JModelica suggest you use the script `/usr/local/jmodelica/bin/jm_python.sh` or what have you to run your JModelica code.

Digging inside of this script, we find the following line:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/root/Ipopt-3.12.4/build/lib/:/usr/local/jmodelica/ThirdParty/Sundials/lib:/usr/local/jmodelica/ThirdParty/CasADi/lib \
```

Note that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is being overwritten, so it does not matter what you set it as!

Changing this line to:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/root/Ipopt-3.12.4/build/lib/:/usr/local/jmodelica/ThirdParty/Sundials/lib:/usr/local/jmodelica/ThirdParty/CasADi/lib \
```

resolves the issues.

This was brought up as a user patch on JModelica's site [here](http://www.jmodelica.org/patch/25942) on 2015-05-03. A patch was submitted on circa Revision 8185 to fix the issue, but it continued to crop up for me on trunk after that.